# Rails whenever cron

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, whenever

Before you read this, understand that I am completely new to the idea of a cron so this is difficult for me. I bundle installed the gem whenever. then i ran

```
wheneverize .
```

no errors. the schedule.rb was created. I have a file called scheduled_scrape.rb when i run

```
ruby script/scheduled_scrape.rb
```

it works perfectly fine. I put in my schedule.rb these lines

```
every 1.minutes do
   command "ruby script/scheduled_scrape.rb" #later on it'll be half an hour, 
   #i just need to test here
end
```

this does nothing. I dug around, and found that perhaps this should be called in terminal (i guess to activate it?)

```
whenever --update-crontab store
```

now, this is still doing nothing. What do i need to do to regularly call my scheduled_scrape.rb

Comment: Have you seen http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby ?

Answer (score 0):

If `store` is the name of your application, then the command should work. So just make sure you call it correctly:

```
whenever --update-crontab <your-app-name>
```

Comment: i had the same whenever setup as him. I took your advice. Its not doing anything

Answer (score 0):

Please check the generated cron job(something like  /bin/bash -l....) by issuing the command "crontab -e" from terminal and try to run the generated command for cron job to check whether it works. If it is not working, try to change the option of the cron job from -l to -i(something like  /bin/bash -i....). Now update the crontab and check whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whenever -i` is the same as `whenever --update-crontab`.

For more info you can check the help with  `whenever -help`.

You can check your cronjobs with the command `crontab -l`